# Quartz Misfire handling with CronoScheduler

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, jobs, quartz.net

I've setup a chrono Job using Quartz library for .NET. Basically, I want a job scheduled every hour and every day at a specific minute (i.e. 10). This is done simply with this chrono expression *0 10 * ? * * **, but how can I achieve the following behavior?:

- if the program at XX:12, then run it immediately
- if the program is started before XX:10, then wait for the chrono scheduler

I've tried this solution but It does not work.

```
  q.AddTrigger(opts =>
          opts.ForJob(job)
              .WithIdentity("CalcServiceJob-trigger")
              .StartNow()
              .WithCronSchedule("0 10 * ? * * *")
      );
```

I've also tried this configuration without relevant results

```
q.AddTrigger(opts =>
          opts.ForJob(job)
              .WithIdentity("CalcServiceJob-trigger")
              .WithCronSchedule("0 10 * ? * * *", x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another trigger that fires immediately and only once against the job:

```cs
q.AddTrigger(t => t
    .ForJob(job)
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithRepeatCount(0).WithInterval(TimeSpan.Zero))
);
```

Comment: This solution works even if the program is started before XX:10. Instead I would like this behavior:
- if the program is started before XX:10, wait for the chrono scheduler
- if the program is started after XX:10, then starts immediately.

Comment: Maybe you can write if clause around the registration?